# For evidence of charitable deduction, does the IRS accept a printout of an e-mail or a screenshot of a text?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, irs, charity

This is a question about **itemized** charitable deductions and the evidence that the United States IRS requires.

Although most of my acknowledgments are still via snail mail, I have several acknowledgements from charities that are in the form of e-mails or texts. They contain all the info the IRS requires.  Will a printout of an e-mail suffice, or does the IRS require the actual original letterhead?  How about a screen shot of a text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When donating money I have kept the email thanking me for the contribution. Or I have downloaded the annual statement from the charity.

From IRS [Topic No. 506 Charitable Contributions](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc506)

> For contributions of cash, check, or other monetary gift (regardless
> of amount), you must maintain a record of the contribution: a bank
> record or a written communication from the qualified organization
> containing the name of the organization, the amount, and the date of
> the contribution.

The IRS doesn't mention a letterhead. I guess that a text is written. I would forward the relevant part of the conversation to my email. If that doesn't work keeping a screen capture with enough details would help.

Documenting stuff being donated is harder.

> In addition to deducting your cash contributions, you generally can
> deduct the fair market value of any other property you donate to
> qualified organizations. See Publication 561, Determining the Value of
> Donated Property.

You not only need an acknowledgement you also need to list the items donated and estimate their value

> For any contribution of $250 or more (including contributions of cash
> or property), you must obtain and keep in your records a
> contemporaneous written acknowledgment from the qualified organization
> indicating the amount of the cash and a description of any property
> contributed. The acknowledgment must say whether the organization
> provided any goods or services in exchange for the gift and, if so,
> must provide a description and a good faith estimate of the value of
> those goods or services. One document from the qualified organization
> may satisfy both the written communication requirement for monetary
> gifts and the contemporaneous written acknowledgment requirement for
> all contributions of $250 or more.

The amount of documenting depends, on the amount donated, and is it money or stuff.